# React and lodash: applying a throttle or debounce to a function while maintaining the event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I have a relatively simply component which looks as follows (simplified)

```
class MouseListener extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.element,
    onMouseMove: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };
  container = null;
  onMouseMove = debounce(e => {
    e.persist();
    const { clientX, clientY } = e;
    const { top, left, height, width } = this.container.getBoundingClientRect();
    const x = (clientX - left) / width;
    const y = (clientY - top) / height;

    this.props.onMouseMove(x, y);
  }, 50);
  render() {
    return (<div
      ref={e => this.container = e}
      onMouseMove={this.onMouseMove}
    >
      {this.props.children}
    </div>);
  }
}
```

However, whenever the `onMouseMove` is triggered, it says that the event has already passed. I expected to be able to use `e.persist()` to keep it in the pool for this event handler to run asynchronously.

What is the appropriate way to bind a debounced event handler in React?

Comment: hmm I haven't had to use `e.persist()` to do this. what happens if you wrap debounce further down? `onMouseMove={debounce(this.onMouseMove, 50)}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the event object with Underscore debounce\[React\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44818463/getting-the-event-object-with-underscore-debouncereact)