# Getting the event object with Underscore debounce[React]

Tags: reactjs, debouncing

I am trying to use debounce on an action I have managed to do that however I want to pass e through  as a parameter but it is not working. Is there any way I could do this?

```
 constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.testing = _.debounce(this.testing.bind(this), 2000);
}

 @action testing(e) {
     alert("debounced!!");
     //use e.target ... 
   }
```

If I take away e it will get into the function otherwise not. What should I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of **[event.persist()](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#event-pooling)** to pass on the event to the debounce method.

According to the DOCS:

> If you want to access the event properties in an `asynchronous` way, you
>   should call `event.persist()` on the event, which will remove the
>   synthetic event from the pool and allow references to the event to be
>   retained by user code.

So you can use the event as

```
constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.testing = _.debounce(this.testing.bind(this), 2000);
}

 @action testing(e) {
     alert("debounced!!");
     //use e.target ... 
   }
onChange = (e) => {
    e.persist();
    this.testing(e);
}
```

Comment: sorry my reputation is not high enough to give a vote:(

Comment: You can accept the answer even if you don't have enough reputation, See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

After assigning `this.testing`,

> this.testing = _.debounce(this.testing.bind(this), 2000);

in some event you should call that method with parameter

```
onSumbit(e){
    this.testing(e);
}
```

something like this

Comment: I tried again and when it reached the point in code of this.testing(e) it says that this.testing is not a function.

Comment: Replace `this.testing = _.debounce(this.testing.bind(this), 2000);` with `this.debounceTesting = _.debounce(this.testing.bind(this), 2000);` and use `this.debounceTesting(e)` instead of `this.testing(e)`, there should be different name for reference pointer and method.